# MySQL Java application works when URL is uses `localhost` but not `127.0.0.1`

Tags: java, mysql, localhost

I'm creating a Java application that uses MySQL for its database.

The program wasn't working and after some trial and error, I found that it worked perfectly when I changed the database address from

`jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/caches`

to

`jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/caches`

But aren't these two the same thing? Why would one work but not the other?

Comment: Is MySQL listening on a TCP port or only using a Unix socket?

Comment: Probably a TCP port. I'm on Windows 8, and using Java Sockets

Answer (score 0):

A likely reason is how MySQL grants are set up. Log in using `localhost` and look at the grant tables using `SHOW GRANTS`, as well as database permissions.

It is very likely that different permissions are set for clients from `127.0.0.1` than `localhost`.

If this isn't the issue, there are [miscellaneous local networking fixes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/can-not-connect-to-server.html) available.